# How do I run g++-4.5?

Tags: 10.10, gcc

I've installed g++-4.5 via apt, and there exists a `/usr/bin/g++-4.5`. However, when I try and run g++-4.5, I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/g++-4.5: not found (hardened-c++ could not find target)
```

In fact, the file /usr/bin/g++-4.5 seems to be a perl script. I understand that Ubuntu uses hardening wrappers around gcc, but I don't know how to actually compile something using g++ in this state.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a poor error message, which indicates that g++-4.5 is not installed. I needed to install [g++-4.5](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/g++-4.5)

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.5
```

(which I thought I had, but I must have installed gcc-4.5 instead).